# No mount point is assigned for the ext4 file system in partition #2 of SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sda)

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, system-installation, preseed

I am installing Ubuntu server with a seed, using RAID partitioning.

I am getting the next message:

> No mount point is assigned for the ext4 file system in partition #2 of
>   SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sda). If you do not go back to the partitioning menu
>   and assign a mount point from there, this partition will not be used
>   at all.

The relevant part of my seed is:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
      multiraid ::                                           \
              1 1 1 free                                     \
                       $gptonly{ }                           \
                       $primary{ }                           \
                       $bios_boot{ }                         \
                       method{ biosgrub }                    \
              .                                              \
              30700 50 30732 raid                            \
                       $primary{ }                           \
                       $bootable{ }                          \
                       method{ raid }                        \
                       format{ }                             \
                       use_filesystem{ }                     \
                       filesystem{ ext4 }                    \
              .                                              \
              500 10000 1000000000 raid                      \
                       method{ raid }                        \
                       format{ }                             \
                       use_filesystem{ }                     \
                       filesystem{ ext4 }                    \
             .                                               \
              24550 512 24600 raid                           \
                       method{ raid }                        \
                       format{ }                             \
              .

d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string \
    0 2 0 ext4 /                    \
          /dev/sda2#/dev/sdb2       \
    .                               \
    0 2 0 ext4 /data                \
          /dev/sda3#/dev/sdb3       \
    .                               \
    0 2 0 swap -                    \
          /dev/sda4#/dev/sdb4       \
    .
```

I get the same error for partitions #3 (sda), #2 (sdb) and #3 (sdb)... When I select  to go back I keep getting the errors and nothing changes, if I select  I get the message:

> Failed to create a file system The ext4 file system creation in
>   partition #2 of SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sda) failed.

If I continue, the same message is shown making it a circle 
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: using Gparted live I saw that both sda and sdb have 4 partitions, like:

> Partition - File System - Mount Point
>
> /dev/sda1 -  grub2 core -
>   /dev/sda2 -  linux-raid -   /dev/md127 
>   /dev/sda3 -  linux-raid -   /dev/md125 
>   /dev/sda4 -  linux-raid -   /dev/md126 
>   /dev/sdb1 -  **unknown**
>   /dev/sdb2 -  linux-raid -   /dev/md127 
>   /dev/sdb3 -  linux-raid -   /dev/md125 
>   /dev/sdb4 -  linux-raid -   /dev/md126

Which indicates that the partitions where kind of successful. but the mount point are extrange, I am going to try to format the disks as this I have read in other questions as a possible solution

Edit 2: After formatting, the same error is encountered

Edit 3: the same happens when using RAID level 1... I thought I might try that since I am running out of ideas :/